# Undo capitalization of directories under root Dropbox directory

Tags: ruby, path, dropbox, dropbox-api, capitalization

I am using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#ruby) [Ruby API](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-ruby-sdk-1.5.1-docs/). When I receive the `"path"` of the directories on the Dropbox server via its API, the directory paths are capitalized if they are directly under the Dropbox root directory, irrespective of whether the corresponding directory on the local computer is capitalized. Given the information on the Dropbox server, how can I achieve the corresponding path on the local computer with the correct alphabet case? Simply applying `downcase` to the given path does not work because some directories on the local computer might actually be capitalized.

Comment: Minor note: are you doing this on mac? If so, the filesystem is case insensitive, so you can access either way.

Comment: @Peter I am doing this on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a case insensitive search for the file in question or just use a case insensitive regex in general. Just be sure to match the full file name unlike the example below:

```
require 'find'

Find.find('.') do |path|
    if path =~ /file_name/i
        p path
    end
end
```

Comment: I didn't know this library at all. It is great.